# Changing the opacity and spacing of images in 'header and footer' for a title page

Tags: spacing, graphics, texmaker, covers

I am trying to create a cover page for my report, however there are a few visuals I would like to modify, as listed below:

- How does one change the opacity of images placed - like the same way Microsoft Word changes the opacity of an image placed in the header.
- How do I position these images sot that the header starts 1cm from the top and the footer 1cm from the bottom. However I only want to apply these settings to the cover page.

Note I am still fairly new to Latex. Thanks
Below is my code and attached is an image of my cover page:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[height = 2.28cm, width = 17cm]{./Figures/Header image.jpg}
\begin{center}
\vspace{1cm}

\Large{\textbf{IB Mathematics SL}}\\
\Large{\textbf{Internal assessment}}\\
\vfill
\line(1,0){400}\\[1mm]
\huge{\textbf{This is a Sample Title}}\\[3mm]
\Large{\textbf{This is a Sample Subtitle}}[1mm]
\line(1,0){400}\\
\vfill

\includegraphics[height = 2.28cm, width = 17cm]{./Figures/Footer image.jpg}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cover page]

Comment: There is the opacity package.  Also tikz and wallpaper.  Note that tikzpagenodes can handle the header and footer locations.

Comment: Thanks. Will make sure I use these packages. Regards